# Rails display alert on site until user adds info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app each user has a customer_added boolean value of false; this changes to true once they add their credit card info. What I'd like to do is display an alert on the site with a link to the credit card info page that is displayed on every page until their customer_added boolean value becomes true (i.e. they add their credit card info). How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Don't use an alert it is not user friendly. What I would do is check for that user if the value is true or false , and based on this present a top navbar with the required information. Your user should have a unique id so you can prob do user.card to get the true/false value. Also this guide may be helpful http://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users

Answer (score 0):

Easy! The way you add something to *every* page is via layout.

Just add something along the lines to your layout where you want to display it (most likely `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`)

```
<% if current_user && !current_user.customer_added %>
  <div class="alert">
    <p>Looks like you haven't added your billing info yet — <%= link_to "add it now", settings_path %>.</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

(Assuming you are using Devise or have otherwise set `current_user` and assuming your stylesheets define what `.alert` looks like.)

So, if you had layout like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Store</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You could insert that straight into the container

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Store</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <% if current_user && !current_user.customer_added %>
    <div class="alert">
      <p>Looks like you haven't added your billing info yet — <%= link_to "add it now", settings_path %>.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```